# How to call intentservice onHandleIntent method repeatedly without creating new intentservice

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I have got an intentservice class called by alarmmanager every 5 seconds. Alarmmanager calls intentservice and it works fine. But when it calls, it creates new intentservice. I just want to call intentService's onHandleIntent method not want to create new one. Here is my code:

**IntentService class:**

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
   private static final String serviceName = "MyIntentService";

   public MyIntentService() {
       super(serviceName);
   }

   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Log.d("Servis", "onCreate()"); //this is called every 5 seconds too
   }

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     //do something
   }
}
```

**Setting alarmManager for IntentService**

```
public void setAlarm(View v)
{
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        long interval = 1000 * 5;
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);

        PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = 
                PendingIntent.getService(context, 12345, serviceIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),interval, servicePendingIntent
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have got an intentservice class called by alarmmanager every 5 seconds.

That will not work on Android 5.1 and higher, where the minimum `setRepeating()` period is 60 seconds. Also, bear in mind that on Android 6.0+, Doze mode and app standby mode mean that you will not get control anywhere near that often for much of the day.

> But when it calls, it creates new intentservice.

That is the point behind `IntentService`. An `IntentService` is destroyed once `onHandleIntent()` ends.

> I just want to call intentService's onHandleIntent method not want to create new one.

Then do not use `IntentService`. Use `Service`, overriding `onStartCommand()` instead of `onHandleIntent()`, and do your own background threading logic. Be sure to stop the service (e.g., `stopSelf()`) when it is no longer needed.